# Как можно в макросе Haxe поменять ключевое слово function на async function

Tags: javascript, haxe, macro

У меня есть простой класс написаный на хаксе:

```
@:expose
class Main implements IAsync {    
    static function main() {
        trace("test");
    }       

    static function testAwait() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

И при конвертации в `JavaScript` он в числе прочего выгоняет метод:

```
. . .
Main.testAwait = function() {
    return Main.test();
};
. . .
```

Мне нужно чтобы макрос менял `function` на `async function` и выгонял что то типа:

```
 . . .
Main.testAwait = async function() {
    return Main.test();
};
. . .
```

Но мне не совсем очевидно как это сделать, если смотреть на стандартные примеры то обычно то содание нового метода будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
package haxe_test;

import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Context;   
using haxe.macro.Tools;
using haxe_test.AsyncBuilder;

class BuildHub {
    macro static public function build():Array<Field> {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        var testFunc:Function = {
            expr: macro return $v{1},
            ret: null,
            params: [],
            args: []
        };

    fields.push({
        name:  "testAwait",
        access:  [Access.AStatic],
        kind: FieldType.FFun(testFunc),
        pos: Context.currentPos(),
    });
    return fields;  
}
```

Но как поменять какоето ключевое слово в рамках какогото таргета например `JavaScript` для нужных мне методов(возможно есть какието опции компилятора или JSGenApi может как то помочь)?